# How to check in Rust if architecture is 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: rust, processor

If there a conditional check for whether processor is 32-bit or 64-bit? I'm looking for kind of configuration check like e.g. `#cfg[x86]` or `cfg[x64]`.

Comment: Do you want to detect this at compile (to enable/disable different functions) or is a runtime detection sufficient? The latter can be done with `if mem::size_of::<usize>() == 8` (and will be optimized out).

Comment: At compile time, to disable portions of code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "64")]` from the [cfg](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html#conditional-compilation) section in [the Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/) seems like a likely solution. It is based on the size of a pointer (as well as `isize` and `usize`), which should correspond to the architecture.

Comment: *which should correspond to the architecture* — not always. For example, AVR chips have 16-bit pointers but are 8-bit architecture.

Comment: So neither is the answer?

Comment: It's more that the question you are asking is not specific enough. Why do you care about the "architecture"? If you care about the size of a pointer, that's one question. If you care about the other aspects, then `target_arch` might be right. If you care about the native CPU size of an integer, then I know of no answer.

Comment: Block sort uses term 64-bit systems when defining FloorOfTwo function. I'm unsure what 64-bit would mean in this context ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_sort#Algorithm

Comment: That seems like a poor explanation of the algorithm then. It probably doesn't mean if the **system** is 64-bit, it means if a specific value has a certain number of bits. In the examples, it's always called with an array length. Since that's a `usize` in Rust, you care about the size of a usize. Although you can probably just use [`usize::next_power_of_two`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.next_power_of_two).

Comment: Sadly, no; `usize::next_power_of_two gives` different results. The algorithm wants lesser power of two e.g. `63u8.next_power_of_two()` should be `32` not `64`. Although some combination of `next_power_of_two` and shift could work.

Answer (score 7):

You should check the Rust Reference chapter on [conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html#conditional-compilation):

> `target_arch = "..."` - Target CPU architecture, such as `"x86"`, `"x86_64"`, `"mips"`, `"powerpc"`, `"powerpc64"`, `"arm"`, or `"aarch64"`. This value is closely related to the first element of the platform target triple, though it is not identical.

Comment: Is there a complete list of these `target_arch` values? One can find a list of `target triples` from [`platform support`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rustc/platform-support.html), but this `target_arch` seems to be not that well documented.