# How do I define a function with different calling conventions depending on the architecture using a macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm developing a small language in Rust. To improve the performance, I'd like to use fastcall calling convention for x86. The `"fastcall"` ABI is not supported for ARM.

For x86:

```
fn add_primitive(&mut self, name: &str, action: extern "fastcall" fn(&mut Self)) {
    ...
}

extern "fastcall" fn a_primitive(&mut self) {}
```

For ARM:

```
fn add_primitive(&mut self, name: &str, action: fn(&mut Self)) {
    ...
}

fn a_primitive(&mut self) {}
```

Using C I can define a macro

```
#ifdef x86
#define PRIMITIVE extern "fastcall" fn
#endif
#ifdef arm
#define PRIMITIVE fn
#endif

fn add_primitive(&mut self, name: &str, action: PRIMITIVE(&mut Self)) {
    ...
}

PRIMITIVE a_primitive(&mut self) {}
```

I do not know how to solve this problem using Rust's macro system.

EDIT:

I need two different macros. I know how to use target_arch to define different versions of functions but not macros.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check in Rust if architecture is 32 or 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896462/how-to-check-in-rust-if-architecture-is-32-or-64-bit) - the question is slightly different, but the answer is the same.

Comment: The answer to [How to check in Rust if architecture is 32 or 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896462/how-to-check-in-rust-if-architecture-is-32-or-64-bit) is not enough for my problem. Because I need two different version of macros. I know how to use target_arch to  define different version of functions but not macros.

Comment: `#[cfg]` works on macros just like it does on functions.

Comment: Be aware that Rust's macros aren't just simple text substitution like they are in C. They have to expand to a whole 'thing' (an item, method, statement, expression, or pattern, to be precise). Your C example won't translate exactly into Rust.

Comment: Generally I have seen stuff like this done by having two versions of the function, both annotated with `target_arch` (or a similar attribute) to determine which ends up in the final build. If they share functionality, pull that out into a separate function and then call it from both.

Comment: IMO, a better approach would be to use generics instead of function pointers, which would let the compiler inline the function call, thus the calling convention becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Please post your solution in an answer, here your previous source https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44369360/4.

Answer (score 2):

```
#[cfg(target_arch = "arm")]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! primitive {
    (fn $args:tt) => { fn $args };
    (fn $f:ident $args:tt $body:tt) => { fn $f $args $body };
    (fn $f:ident $args:tt -> isize $body:tt) => { fn $f $args -> isize $body };
}

#[cfg(target_arch = "x86")]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! primitive {
    (fn $args:tt) => { extern "fastcall" fn $args };
    (fn $f:ident $args:tt $body:tt) => { extern "fastcall" fn $f $args $body };
    (fn $f:ident $args:tt -> isize $body:tt) => { extern "fastcall" fn $f $args -> isize $body };
}
```

Example:

```
pub struct Word<Target> {
    symbol: Symbol,
    is_immediate: bool,
    is_compile_only: bool,
    hidden: bool,
    dfa: usize,
    cfa: usize,
    action: primitive!{ fn (&mut Target) },
    pub(crate) compilation_semantics: fn(&mut Target, usize),
}

primitive!{fn dup(&mut self) {
    let slen = self.s_stack().len.wrapping_add(1);
    self.s_stack().len = slen;
    self.s_stack()[slen.wrapping_sub(1)] = self.s_stack()[slen.wrapping_sub(2)];
}}
```

Comment: Can you put an example of how to use it?

Comment: @Boiethios This is a wiki answer feel free to improve it, I just create it because OP had answer in the question. I have no idea about how this work or what is the purpose.

Comment: I used it in my own Forth to define primitive forth words. Please see https://github.com/chengchangwu/rtforth/blob/master/src/core.rs .